# how to show html code as text in android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android

want put html code like code tutorial description so 
i want to show html code in activity like given website link below

At the end of the HTML tutorial, you can find more than 200 examples.

With our online editor, you can edit and test each example yourself.

Comment: i want to create tutorial code example https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MichaelHancock you need to click flag>duplicate>put link in box> and click flag question

Comment: i want to show only code in textvew or edit text

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad, I didn't know that

Comment: oh my god that very sad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to show html code in a textview then click on button show output of html code......... – Sachin Srivastava

add below library in your build.gradle file

```
//for html to text
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
```

and

```
TextView txt_htmltext;
Button btn;

txt_htmltext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_htmltext);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

txt_htmltext.setText(R.string.temp_html_text);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        txt_htmltext.setText(html2text(txt_htmltext.getText().toString()));
    }
});

public String html2text(String html) {
    try {
        return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

res/values/string.xml:

```
<string name="temp_html_text"><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Page Title</title> </head> <body> <h1>This is a Heading</h1> <p>This is a paragraph.</p> </body> </html>]]></string>
```

XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3sp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_htmltext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="@string/temp_html_text"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="html to text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its working but not alignment of code.

Comment: @SachinSrivastava 
You can't get exact output like <h1> header tag  </h1> or any alignment in android,
use instead, 
to get exact HTML output, create a file1.html file and put it in your asset folder and call it in Webview.

Comment: yes Dhiren sir i use it & work properly thanks a lot Dhiren sir

Comment: how to accept sir plz tell me where button or link

Comment: @SachinSrivastava wlcm

Answer (score 1):

add below library in your build.gradle file

```
//for html to text
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
```

and use below method to get your html code as text in android.

```
public String html2text(String html) {
    try {
        return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return "";
    }
}

String myhtmlcode = "<p>its my html code</p>";

yourTextView.settext(html2text(myhtmlcode));
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: i want to show html code in a textview then click on button show output of html code.........

Comment: above code convert HTML code as a text merely, as you mentioned in your question.
you should create necessary if else condition as your requirement. and its easy to handle.